# Spring MQTT integration: loss of messages

Tags: spring, spring-integration, mqtt

I'm trying use spring integration to receive a big amount of MQTT messages, process them and then store in a db.

Here is the code:

```
@Bean
public MqttPahoClientFactory mqttClientFactory() {
    DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory factory = new DefaultMqttPahoClientFactory();
    factory.setServerURIs("tcp://localhost:1883");
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public DefaultPahoMessageConverter messageConverter(){
    DefaultPahoMessageConverter converter = new DefaultPahoMessageConverter();
    converter.setPayloadAsBytes(true);
    return converter;
}

@Bean
public MessageChannel mqttInputChannel() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}


@Bean
public MessageProducer mqttInbound() {
    MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter adapter =
            new MqttPahoMessageDrivenChannelAdapter("clientID", mqttClientFactory(), "topic1");
    adapter.setCompletionTimeout(5000);
    adapter.setConverter(messageConverter());
    adapter.setQos(2);
    adapter.setOutputChannel(mqttInputChannel());
    return adapter;
}

@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "mqttInputChannel")
public MessageHandler handler(){

    return new MessageHandler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message<?> arg0) throws MessagingException {
            //process messages and storing operations   
        }
    };
}
```

My problem is that I'm not able to receive all messages and losing some of them, probably because I spend a lot of resources and time inside the handler method. I've tried also to use a QueueChannel instead of the DirectChannel, but when the queue is full the problem remains. 
A possible solution could be this, stop the reception till the message is completely handled and then restarts it, but I don't know how. Any advice?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "losing"? - when using a direct channel the messages will be delivered at the rate your handler can manage.

Comment: Trying to receive a lot of messages using a direct channel, happens that some of them aren't handled by the message handler and I'm not able to manage them, having a loss. I've tried to use a queue channel and this solve my problem until the queue has space remained, when it's full the problem appears again.

Comment: "some of them aren't handled" makes no sense - you need to be clearer what you mean. Using a queue channel won't help and will likely cause you to lose messages in the event of a server failure.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I discovered that the loss I was talking depends by the broker configuration and not by the channel as I tought. And, as you say, using a direct channel works perfectly.